# React class methods overriding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create some kind of class composition in react:

```
class Entity {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  renderPartial() {
    return (<div>Entity</div>)
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>header {this.renderPartial()}</div>);
  }
}

class Person extends Entity{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  renderPartial() {
    return (<div>Person</div>)
  }
}

class Manager extends Person {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderPartial() {
    return (<div>Manager</div>)
  }
}
```

In the following example `Person` extends from `Entity` class. And the goal here is to render partial content inside of the extended class. So for the simplicity sake I just render class name. This way everything works fine with Person class and it renders its text. But when I extend Manager from Person it writes `<div>Person</div>` and I can't understand why. Is there any way to override `renderPartial` inside of the `Manager` class?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Maybe a typo in the method name?

Comment: @Bergi I am starting to think that this approach isn't working with react( Because in es6 it works fine https://gist.github.com/berdof/a54d43c289bf6787ad02

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use inheritance in React (other than extending `React.Component`). It's not the recommended approach. More on this [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/613#issuecomment-29280175). (See also [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-two-pillars-of-javascript-ee6f3281e7f3#.ylfz30430).)

If you need outer and inner components, you can use `this.props.children`. e.g.

```
render() {
  return <div>header {this.props.children}</div>;
}
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
<Entity>
  <Person />
</Entity>
```

But usually even this is unnecessary. Simply split your components into smaller pieces. e.g.

```
<div>
  <Header />
  <Person />
</div>
```

Small, modular components are much easier to manage than gargantuan objects with long inheritance chains.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with your code posted above: `super()` should only be used in a derived constructor. Since `Entity` doesn't extend any class, `super()` doesn't make any sense in this context, and throws a syntax error using ES6 transpiled with babel.

Rendering your code in a browser will also produce a warning: "React component classes must extend React.Component" - your classes should extend `React.Component`, as below.

As mentioned below, inheritance is not the recommended or 'React' way to share code between components ([composition is the way forward](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.t5quo2m53)). For something as simple as your example, you would probably want to use a single component multiple times with different props:

```
class Entity extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>header {this.props.headerType}</div>
  }
}

Entity.defaultProps = {
  headerType: 'Entity'
}

<Entity /> // renders <div>header Entity</div>
<Entity entityType ='Person' /> // renders <div>header Person</div>
<Entity entityType ='Manager' /> // renders <div>header Manager</div>
```

If you want to retain your named components, you can simply wrap the `<Header>` component and set the prop:

```
class Person extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <Entity entityType='Person' />
  }
}

<Entity /> // renders <div>header Entity</div>
```

However, for more complex code reuse, you might want to explore higher order components - essentially functions that wrap and return components.

```
let entityComponent = function(Component) {

  class EntityComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          header <Component {...this.props} />
        </div>
      );
    }

  }

  EntityComponent.defaultProps = {
    headerType: 'Entity'
  }

  return EntityComponent;

}

class Entity extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <span>{this.props.headerType}</span>
    );
  }

}

Entity = entityComponent(Entity);

<Entity /> // renders <div>header <span>Entity</span></div>

class Person extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <span>{this.props.headerType}</span>
    );
  }

}

Person = entityComponent(Person);

<Person headerType='Person' /> // renders <div>header <span>Person</span></div>
```

A combination of these techniques should enable you to achieve what you want!